# Cannot import name 'TextFace' error while using ETE3 for Phylogeny Tree

Tags: python, bioinformatics, fasta, phylogeny, ete3

I am trying to install ETE3 for phylogeny analysis but while installing it is showing error:cannot import name 'TextFace'

I tried all the available options but could not succeed.

Any help will be appreciated.

PS: I am trying to build Phylogeny tree from FASTA format using Python. If there any other better option is available please also suggest.

```
sudo yum install PyQt4.x86_64 numpy.x86_64 python-lxml.x86_64 python-six.noarch
pip install --upgrade ete3
ete3 upgrade-external-tools
ete3 build check
```

**Traceback (most recent call last):**

> File "/home/user1/.local/bin/ete3", line 5, in 
> from ete3.tools.ete import main
>
> File
> "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ete3/tools/ete.py",
> line 55, in
>
> from . import (ete_split, ete_expand, ete_annotate, ete_ncbiquery, ete_view,   File
> "/home/user1/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/ete3/tools/ete_view.py",
>
> line 48, in 
> from .. import (Tree, PhyloTree, TextFace, RectFace, faces, TreeStyle, CircleFace, AttrFace,
>
> ImportError: cannot import name 'TextFace'

Comment: This [issue](https://github.com/etetoolkit/ete/issues/195) talks about the problem at hand and possible solutions.